# What kind of non-toxic bait can be used an alternative to mouse baits or pellets?

Tags: pest-control, pest

I recently purchased a mouse trap. The instructions said to use bait pellets. However, what is a cheaper, more readily available alternative to bait pellets which will not kill the mice?

[image: picture of a trap designed to catch mice live and not kill them. Have a heart trap]

Maybe peanut butter, but I do not know if it might or might not be toxic to mice.

[image: photograph of instructions which says, "put baits on the bait hook"]

Comment: I've found that mice like peanuts and peanut butter and I really doubt that it's in any way toxic to them.  But I also found that they seem to like sunflower butter and sunflower seeds even better.  I spread a bit of sunflower butter on the trigger of the trap and then stick a few seeds into it.  But PB works well if you don't have sunflower stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Raw bacon! Or smoked one.**

Different types of sausage also work to a different extent.

The cartoon image of a mouse and a piece of cheese is somewhat misleading - cheese dries quickly and the smell goes away. And it is not as attractive to mice and rats as bacon in the first place.

---

p.s. It looks like the rodents (and most other animals, in fact) prioritize food by its calorific value. Of course, the mouse has to know there is food in the first place, this is why the distinct smell is also important for a good bait.

Good luck catching them.

Answer (score 0):

Peanut butter has worked fairly well for me. It is not toxic to mice.